# How do I retrieve the ID of a parent that points to a child?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, ef-code-first

VS2013, code first EF6, SQL database, VB

I defined the following classes:

```vb
Public Class Question
  Public Property QuestionID As Integer
  Public Property Text As String
  Public Property Type As qType
  Public Property PossibleAnswers As New List(Of qAnswer)
End Class

Public Class qAnswer
  Public Property qAnswerID As Integer
  Public Property Text As String
End Class
```

When I view the qAnswer data table created in the SQL server I see:

[image]

In order to do something so simple as display a list of all answers and their parent questions I need to retrieve the value that is obviously in the table, but I don't understand how to code it.  Since it's not technically a property of the class I can't call for it directly.  How do I retrieve that value?

I'd like to know if the manner of retrieval will work in both the source code, meaning VB, and the view code, meaning Razor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you created a navigation property to `qAnswer` on `Question`, Entity Framework created an implicit foreign key to `Question` on `qAnswer` to store the relationship. This results in the `Question_QuestionID` property you see in your database table. However, since this is an implicit property, there's no way to directly access its value in code. You have two options, and you might want to actually do both.

1. Add a reference property to `qAnswer`. If you don't actually care about the related question id, explicitly, and just want to be able to get at the question itself, then you can do so through the reference property. Just add something like the following to `qAnswer`:

   ```
   Public Property Question As Question
   ```
2. If you want the id, itself, then you need a property to on `qAnswer` to store it. Something like:

   ```
   Public Property QuestionID As Integer
   ```

   By convention, Entity Framework will recognize this as the foreign key property for the relationship and use it accordingly. You'll need to run a migration after adding this property for it to take effect.

Comment: Solution 2 worked great; everything was simple after that change. I have no need to actually 'look' at a question from the perspective of an answer, I just needed to use that value in navigation; so I didn't try solution 1, but I see how that would work. Just to make sure I fully understand solution 1, can I not also retrieve the ID there as well?

Comment: You could, via something like `answer.Question.QuestionID`. However, that requires actually loading the `Question` instance from the database in order to retrieve the id. By having the foreign key property, as well, in this scenario, you can avoid loading the `Question` if all you need is the id.

Comment: Got it! In this case solution 2 really is the answer for my current situation because solution 1 would gain me nothing with another query to the database, though solution 1 would certainly be useful in other situations and needed to be posted here for future reference.